# Package Problem with Ant

Tags: java, ant

I'm having a problem getting the javac used by Ant to find and use certain packages. When I invoke javac directly from the command line the packages are found and used.

The .jar files are located in my home directory under `lib/java`. This is my classpath:
`/home/bliskovs/lib/java/*:/home/bliskovs/vendor/cytoscape-v2.7.0/cytoscape.jar`

This is the relevant section in my `build.xml`:

```
  <target name="compile">
    <javac srcdir="." debug="true"/>
    <javac srcdir="tools/" debug="true"/>
    <javac srcdir="core/" debug="true"/>
  </target>
```

How can I get Ant to recognize these packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this.

```
<property name="build.classes.dir" location="build/classes"/>

<path id="compile.classpath">
     <fileset dir="lib"/>
     <pathelement location="/home/bliskovs/vendor/cytoscape-v2.7.0"/>
</path>

<target name="compile" description="Compile src dir">
  <javac destdir="${build.classes.dir}" debug="true" includeantruntime="true">
    <src location="src"/>
    <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
  </javac>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a classpath for the `javac` task. Relying on the CLASSPATH environment variable is a bad practice. It's even more true for the build process of a project, which should work without having to setup a whole lot of environment variables. If you start developing three or four projects at once, you'll understand why using a single CLASSPATH env variable is a bad idea.

See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html to know how to define a classpath inside the build.xml and use it in the `javac` task.